# Ambari show namenode is stop but actually namenode is still working

Tags: hadoop, ambari

We are using HDP 2.7.1.2.3  with Ambari 2.1.2

After finish setup, every node status is correct.
But oneday ambari suddenly show namdenode is stopped.(we don't change any config of ambari or namenode)
However, we still can use HBASE and run MapReduce.
we think name node status should be normal.

We try to restart namenode and check ambari-server log
It shows:

> ServiceComponentHostImpl:949 - Host role transitioned to a new state, serviceComponentName=NAMENODE, oldState=STARTING, currentState=STARTED
>   HeartBeatHandler:657 - State of service component NAMENODE of service HDFS of cluster wae has changed from STARTED to INSTALLED

we don't understand why its status change from "STARTED" to "INSTALLED".
In namenode side, we check ambari-agent.log
It shows one warning:

> [Alert][namenode_directory_status] HA nameservice value is present but there are no aliases for {{hdfs-site/dfs.ha.namenodes.{{ha-nameservice}}}}

We think it is irrelevant.

What's the reason that ambari think namenode is stopped?
Is there any way that we can fix this issue?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Run the command **ambari-server restart** from linux terminal in Ambari server node

Run the command **ambari-agent restart** from linux terminal in all the nodes in the cluster.

You can run the command **hdfs dfsadmin -report** from the terminal as hdfs user to confirm all the nodes are up and running.

Comment: I run the hdfs dfsadmin -report. Report shows data node status but no status of name node.

Comment: What you mean by no status for namenode ? Is it in safe mode ? If yes, then you can try **hadoop fs -safemode leave** to leave the safe mode.

Comment: The report is as below: Configured Capacity: xxx
Present Capacity: xxx
DFS Remaining: xxx
DFS Used: xxx
DFS Used%: xxx
Under replicated blocks: xxx
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (3):

Name: data node 1Decommission Status : Normal, Name: data node 2 Decommission Status: Normal, Name: data node 3 Decommission Status: Normal,

Comment: I see the hdfs report looks fine. Have you tried restarting the HDFS from Ambari UI, then restarting the ambari-server and ambari-agent as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes. we try to restart HDFS from ambari UI. name node will show "started" for a while and then change to "stopped"